# Apache Solr indexing and filter query

Tags: solr, lucene

I need some information about Solr indexing I cannot find. I'm wondering whether fields on which I want to apply only a filter query have to be indexed or it is sufficient to mark them as stored.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to lucidworks solr ref guide which can be downloaded for free.

Table for field attributes and use case mapping :-

[image]

Comment: What about **fq** (Filter Query)?

Comment: Why a downvote? Please add a comment so I can improve my answer if its no longer valid !!!!

Answer (score 0):

yes, it must be indexed. It does not need to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

store and index are totally different concepts on Solr. If you want to make query on your fields then you should set **indexed=true**. If you also want to retrieve data when you query then you should set **stored=true**.

So, for your question; Yes you should set **indexed=true** if you want to make query.